# ?: doesn't work correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript

I written the following code to change the numbers to Persian:

```
function farsi(x) {
    x = x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    var a = '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'; var b = ''; 
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        var c = x.charCodeAt(i); 
        b += (c >= 48 || c <= 57 ? a.charAt(c - 48) : x.charAt(i));
     }
     return b;
 }
```

I have used the regex for thousand seprator from [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript) which works correctly. But the separator character is not being added in this line of code:

```
b += (c >= 48 || c <= 57 ? a.charAt(c - 48) : x.charAt(i));
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qvwzs5e/1)

Comment: You are missing parentheses from the condition: b += ((c >= 48 || c <= 57) ? a.charAt(c - 48) : x.charAt(i));

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: @Pavel that link leads to the czech translation. Here it is in english: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: type error.....

Comment: @Esko I added the parentheses and it still not working.

Comment: "Not working" is not enough information, is there an error, wrong output or what. Please explain and add [mcve] that we can run and see the problem.

Comment: @Fildor thx for fix. Since this article was not translated yet and it it in english, I didn't realize that this link is supposed to be localized

Comment: @Esko well not working means that the separator comma is still missing in the output.

Comment: I tried it and its working it does show to comma as seperator

Comment: @Beginner in the output? the first alert is to test the regex which shows the comma. the second alert is the real output which is missing the comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put || instead of &&

```
b += (c >= 48 && c <= 57 ) ? a.charAt(c - 48) : x.charAt(i);
```

see the working code
https://jsfiddle.net/4qvwzs5e/2/